# Java MalformedURLException unable to fix

Tags: java, exception

I'm ironing out the issues in my code for a lab that displays pictures from a url but keep getting the output: "Oh oh, something bad happened." from the given code in the catch block

I've been searching around trying to figure out how to fix the url issues, and I tried retyping the double quotes and the http:// and ran the url with no issues in the browser. I can't seem to figure out where I'm getting the exception from

*These methods were given by the professor*

The file name http://venus.cs.qc.cuny.edu/~aabreu/cs212/images/

This is the code that calls the URL

```
public void loadImages() {
    Document doc;
    String url = "http://venus.cs.qc.cuny.edu/~aabreu/cs212/images/";
    int j = 0;
    try {
        System.out.println("Reading URL directory");
        doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        Elements files = doc.getElementsByTag("a");
        // initialize the array size for the filenames
        picture = new String[files.size()];
        for (Element file : files) {
            String filename = file.attr("href");
            if (filename.indexOf(".jpg") >= 0 || filename.indexOf(".gif") >= 0) {
                System.out.println(filename);
                picture[j++] = url + filename;
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

*/

```
public synchronized void drawPict(String fileName) {
    try {
        System.out.println(fileName); // FileName is a local file
        // ImageIcon imgIcon = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(fileName)); //
        // FileName is an URL
        ImageIcon imgIcon = new ImageIcon(new URL(fileName));
        pict = imgIcon.getImage();
        if (pict != null) {
            MediaTracker imageTracker = new MediaTracker(this);
            imageTracker.addImage(pict, 0);
            try {
                imageTracker.waitForAll();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
            parent.setVisible(false);
            this.setSize(pict.getWidth(this), pict.getHeight(this));
            parent.setSize(pict.getWidth(this), pict.getHeight(this));
            parent.setVisible(true);
            repaint();
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
        System.out.println("Oh oh, something bad happened");
    }
}
```

Comment: You are swallowing the exception. In the `catch` block, try `throw new RuntimeException(mue)` instead of `System.out.println("Oh oh, something bad happened")`. That will tell you where/why it failed.

Comment: What does `filename` look like? If it's `http://venus.cs.qc.cuny.edu/~aabreu/cs212/images/foo.jpg` bad things are going to happen...

Comment: I tried most of the code in drawPict outside of `parent` and `this` and with the file name you referenced in the question, I didn't have any issues. You'll need to update your catch to get the stack trace and include those details in the question.